# Recurly Paypal integration

Tags: paypal, integration, recurly

Recurring billing API call from Recurly to PayPal is failing and the error code returned is 11451 (Billing Agreement Id or transaction Id is not valid). However, the Billing Agreement Id is still in ACTIVE status in PayPal. Any idea, what API call is made by Recurly to PayPal ? How can I get the logs for the same?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this issue was due to type of Billing Agreement created. Recurly needs a Billing Agreement ID which supports reference transactions, for them to process the future payments. However the REST API SDK supported billing agreement is not a Reference Transaction type, it is just a recurring payment type.

To solve this issue, we used the PayPal Merchant SDK (which refers NVP/SOAP APIs) for creating the reference transaction, instead of PayPal SDK (which refers REST APIs).

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to email support@recurly.com on this one, with the code you are using and response from the API. This is likely a site-specific issue, so not something that can be resolved via SO.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. Contacted both Recurly and PayPal support and sorted this out.